# Last insert id in laravel and mongo db using query builder?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

How can I get the last inserted `id` after inserting a row in laravel and MongoDB? My code for inserting a row is:

```
$insertData = DB::collection('hotels')->insert($insertArray);
```

Comment: can you tell us what package you currently using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `insertGetId` as following.

```
$insertid = DB::collection('hotels')->insertGetId($insertArray);
```